# node.js - mongodb to ejs - render entire collection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

I've been following this tutorial and I want to do something similar to the userlist page, the only difference, I want to use ejs instead of jade.

In html, the end result should look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="users/testuser1">testuser1</a></li>
    <li><a href="users/testuser2">testuser2</a></li>
    <li><a href="users/testuser3">testuser3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the index.js file, I have code like this:

```
/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

In jade, this is how it looks:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="users/#{user.username}")= user.username
```

Basically, I want to do this in ejs. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To use ejs instead of jade, first you need to configure view engine to the express frame work. This could be done as below.

```
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');   // ejs in your case.
```

also you need specify the location for ejs files using the below line of code

```
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));   // here views is folder name inside of the project folder.
```

and then you have use the below code in xxx.ejs file.

```
 <ul>
  <% userlist.forEach(function(user) { %>
    <li><a href="users/#<%= user.username %>"><%= user.username %></a></li>
   <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt need the hashtag though. That was just for jade.

Answer (score 0):

To show users in a ul list you can try something like this:

```
<ul>
   <% userlist.forEach(function(user) { %>
     <li><a href="users/#<%= user.username %>"><%= user.username %></a></li>
   <% } %>
</ul>
```

Here is a good tutorial to help you out! : https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need the hashtag though. That was just for jade I think to escape. But the tutorial link your provided is useful, so thanks for that too.